# Dependency 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M5' not found

Tags: maven, junit, dependencies, pom.xml

[Dependency Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AKpG.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>StandardPomFile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <dependencies>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
         <scope>test</scope></dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>

Dependency 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M5' not found
```

I am not too familiar with Maven or dependencies so respond like I know nothing, because i probably don't.

This is a school project where I am supposed to run Junit tests on this contact book service program that I created but I cannot seem to figure out how to add Junit as a dependency or how to create a Junit file.

Comment: First check on plain command furthermore use the most recent version of the dependency and also based on your screen shot your project is misconfigured ... the tests should be located in `src/test/java/<package>` and your production code in `src/main/java/<package>` etc.

Comment: I will change the configuration, I was able to get the dependency to work but for some reason, Junit is still not a file that I can create. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you fetched the Maven dependecy? Right click on `pom.xml` -> `Maven` -> `Reload project`. Also have you done `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Please try to build first on plain command line not from without your IDE... just a `mvn clean verify` and see if everything is working..